# How to display a loading page while java application is still compiling?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, spring

How can I display a loading page while java is compiling?

[image: Browser loading up]

Currently, I have a spring boot application that loads up going to local host. My current application take about 15-30 secs to finish compiling.
I used jquery to display loading gif while page is loading. But It does not display my loading page until my java/spring boot application is done loading.  It will display the current page i'm on until my java/spring boot app is done running then it will briefly show my loading page (when loading data onto page).

How can I display the loading page as my java application is still compiling? Display a page of my choice rather than a current page i'm on.

**MyAttempt**

**Index.html**

```
<!-- Jquery  -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
})
</script>
<body>
<div class="loader">

<!-- my code -->

</div>
```

**style.css**

```
    .loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('ajax-loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}
```

This is a example provided by http://bradsknutson.com/blog/display-loading-image-while-page-loads/

**Update**

Basically my page will stay on the current page while having the browser loading circle loading(next to "New Tab" img above). After that I will receive my loading page(with code above) and then display my data. I do not wish to stay on the current page, I want my loading page to display while the (circle on the browser is loading(next to "New Tab" img above).

Comment: "How can I display the loading page as soon as the browsers loading icon is showing?" <- Since the browser first has to load your loading page, this is strictly speaking not possible. There will allways be a small delay.

Comment: Unfortunately, according to my understanding, this is not possible. The initial stage of a get request, where you're still on your currently active site, is the fetch. The speed of this is usually dependent on the server, and until this step is finished, the browser doesn't have enough information to display anything.

Comment: Thank you, It is not possible to add a script into java to redirect to a page, until the page is loaded up? I know the attempt I did will not work because it waits till my java/spring app is done loading before it even reads my html pages.

Comment: @911DidBush Prior to the small delay, is it possible to display a html page before the application starts? Or when the app start display the html loading page.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I display the loading page as soon as the browsers loading icon is showing?

By serving a lightweight page with the loading indicator, which in turn either uses ajax to request the heavy page content that's taking so long to load or redirects to it.

Comment: Can I use java to display a html page on localhost:8080 until it is done compiling then redirect to the intended page?

Answer (score 0):

You could also implement a JS service worker which tells the user, if the site is offline.

But for this to work the user needs to be at least once on the page to download an register the service-worker.

So first create an offline.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Offline</title>
</head>
<body>
    Site currently compiling...
    <script>
        setInterval(() => location.href = '/', 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in your main site append this js line somewhere:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
    .then(() => console.log("Service Worker registered"))
    .catch((err) => console.warn("Error:" + err));
```

And create your service-worker (straight out of https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/11/offline-service-workers/):

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    // Put `offline.html` page into cache
    var offlineRequest = new Request('offline.html');
    event.waitUntil(
        fetch(offlineRequest).then(function(response) {
            return caches.open('offline').then(function(cache) {
                return cache.put(offlineRequest, response);
            });
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    // Only fall back for HTML documents.
    var request = event.request;
    // && request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html')
    if (request.method === 'GET') {
        // `fetch()` will use the cache when possible, to this examples
        // depends on cache-busting URL parameter to avoid the cache.
        event.respondWith(
            fetch(request).catch(function(error) {
                // `fetch()` throws an exception when the server is unreachable but not
                // for valid HTTP responses, even `4xx` or `5xx` range.
                return caches.open('offline').then(function(cache) {
                    return cache.match('offline.html');
                });
            })
        );
    }
    // Any other handlers come here. Without calls to `event.respondWith()` the
    // request will be handled without the ServiceWorker.
});
```

Now every time your page goes down the offline page will be shown.

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a solution description here. Post code that demonstrates 
your solution. Thanks!